# Getting RGB values and blob data for StickFigure

Tags: kinect

I am using OPENNI and NITE ,I am trying to get 3 types of info from the StickFigure sample provided by PrimeSense ,

1. X,Y & Z Coordinates of each joints - I could do this, Example for Left hand, the following function, will return x,y,z coordinates into BXN_SKEL_LEFT_HAND object g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().GetSkeletonJointPosition(user,XN_SKEL_LEFT _HAND , BXN_SKEL_LEFT_HAND);

Now i need help with the following two::

1. How do I get the RGB values for the same ?
2. How do I get the data associated with the boundaries of the StickFigure, when I mean boundaries i mean the blob data or the data which is associated with flesh/outline part of the human for which the stick figure is being recognized ?

Any suggestions or solutions are highly appreciated.

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

1. RGB values come from the the camera image data.
   This is simply a 640x480 array of RGB values.
   So to get the RGB value at 300,200, simply read the value from the camera image at [300,200].
2. Unfortunately, blob data is in the realm of point clouds, so the camera and OpenNI will not contain any functions to find this data.
   I would suggest looking at the point cloud library to help you here.
   ( http://pointclouds.org/ )
   Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

1. xnConvertRealWorldToProjective (depthGenerator.ConvertRealWorldToProjective with the C++ wrapper) will convert a point in world-space (like what you get from the skeleton) back to 2d pixel coordinates in the depth map.
   Enable depth-registration by doing something along the lines of depthGenerator.GetAlternativeViewpointCap().SetAlternativeViewpoint(imageGenerator).

   This modifies the depth to appear as if it was captured from the RGB CMOS's position (e.g. depth and rgb pixels will align exactly) so you can use the coordinates from one in the other (except for maybe scaling x,y due to resolution differences).
2. your users generator node has a function called GetUserPixels (e.g. users.GetUserPixels(0, sceneMD)), which will fill the scene metadata object with a label map - a 16-bpp pixel map where every pixels is the identifier of the user who owns the pixel, or 0 if the pixel doesn't belong to a user.

   Example usage of this is available at the NiUserTracker sources (this is how they colorize users differently than the background), see the sources at OpenNI\Samples\NiUserTracker (SceneDrawer.cpp is interesting).